# How to properly use -display when starting a program from a shell

Tags: linux, xorg

I'm shelled into a linux machine, and I intend to run a program to display on the remote machine. However, I cannot remember how to set the proper xorg parameters. For the purpose of this "lesson", let's presume that I want to run `xeyes`. I remember something along the lines of `xeyes -display 0:0`, but the screen designation is what's thrown me off:

1. What is the correct syntax?
2. What do the digits in the `-display` flag indicate?
3. Using XFCE (if that's relevant), what's the correct designation for "first (and only) monitor, second desktop" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for the `-display` option is *<xserver>*`:`*<displaynumber>*`.`*<screennumber>*

As for how the numbers relate to your displays, that's an implementation detail for the display manager in question.  I don't know how XFCE works in particular, so it could be any of these possibilities:

1. Your login uses display `:0` for all monitors, with the first monitor being `:0.0`, second monitor being `:0.1`, etc., in which case there would be no way to identify the virtual desktops hosted on each screen.
2. Your login uses display `:0` for the first monitor and display `:1` for the second monitor.  There are two sub-cases for this:

   1. The display manager doesn't directly understand the virtual desktops, and so you only have `:#.0` as display options that connect to the current virtual desktop shown on that display.
   2. The display manager *does* understand the virtual desktops and allows the "screen number" to represent the virtual desktop number, so `:0.1` would be the second virtual desktop on the first monitor.

Comment: I know, it's been over three years... I've been "busy"... Would I be correct in interpreting your answer as not specifying the xserver before the colon, i.e. leaving it blank, makes it refer to the one running locally?

Comment: yes, leaving off the server part of the display means connecting to the server running locally (literally `localhost`)